# Given a Model, how to loop through all properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to loop through all the properties of my 'user' model, how can I do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you have an instance of your model then `user.attributes` is a Hash of the model's attributes and their values so, for example, you can do something like:

```
user.attributes.each_pair do |name, value|
  puts "#{name} = #{value}"
end
```

If you don't have a specific instance then the class has methods that return information about the fields in the database e.g. `User.columns` and `User.content_columns`. e.g.

```
User.columns.each do |column|
  puts column.name
end
```

Comment: This is deprecated as of rails 4, what's the right solution now?

Comment: Which of the methods mentioned are deprecated? They all still seem to be in the API docs.

Comment: That worked great for me on Rails 4.2.2. Thanks mikej.

Answer (score 1):

```
Article.columns.each do |column|
  puts column.name
end
```

This iterates over all the column objects for the Article model.

Answer (score 1):

@model.methods returns the names of all methods of the object.

@model.methods.grep(/=$/) will return you the names of all write methods, so you can guess that if you have a setter, then you also have a reader, so this may be a "property".

You may also inspect the attributes hash (@model.attributes) which is a Hash with all the columns defined in the database, and this may be the most reliable way, since the "methods" method may not include the attribute readers (and writers) generated dynamically. (It may depend on the version of RubyOnRails you are using).